# Easiest way to reshape this dataframe in R?

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2, melt, tidyr

Say I have the following wide/messy dataframe:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2), Gender = c("M","F"),
       Q1 = c(1, 5), Q2 = c(2, 6),
       Q3 = c(3, 7), Q4 = c(4, 8))

 ID Gender Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
 1      M  1  2  3  4
 2      F  5  6  7  8
```

how can I turn it into this dataframe:

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2), Gender = c("M", "M", "F", "F"),
       V1 = c(1, 3, 5, 7), V2 = c(2, 4, 6, 8))

 ID Gender V1 V2
 1      M  1  2
 1      M  3  4
 2      F  5  6
 2      F  7  8
```

I know there are multiple packages and functions (e.g., tidyr, reshape2, reshape function) that can accomplish this. Which is the easiest way to do it and how? Really appreciate any help anyone can provide. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun! I'll stick with reshape for now because I'm still trying to learn data.table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `melt` from the devel version of `data.table` i.e `v1.9.5`.  It can take multiple variables in the `measure.vars` as a list. Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
melt(setDT(df1), measure.vars=list(c(3,5), c(4,6)), 
  value.name=c('V1', 'V2'))[,variable:=NULL][order(ID)]
#   ID Gender V1 V2
#1:  1      M  1  2
#2:  1      M  3  4
#3:  2      F  5  6
#4:  2      F  7  8
```

Or use `reshape` from `base R`

```
res <- subset(reshape(df1, idvar=c('ID', 'Gender'), 
       varying=list(c(3,5), c(4,6)), direction='long'), select=-time)
row.names(res) <- NULL
```

#### Update

If we need to transform back the 'df2' to 'df1', `dcast` from `data.table` could be used.  It can take multiple `value.var` columns.  We need to create a sequence column (`N`) by group ('ID', 'Gender') before proceeding with `dcast`

```
 dcast(setDT(df2)[, N:=1:.N, list(ID, Gender)], ID+Gender~N, 
           value.var=c('V1', 'V2'))
 #   ID Gender 1_V1 2_V1 1_V2 2_V2
 #1:  1      M    1    3    2    4
 #2:  2      F    5    7    6    8
```

Or we create a sequence by group with `ave` and then use `reshape` from `base R`.

```
  df2 <- transform(df2, N= ave(seq_along(ID), ID, Gender, FUN=seq_along))
 reshape(df2, idvar=c('ID', 'Gender'), timevar='N', direction='wide')
 #   ID Gender V1.1 V2.1 V1.2 V2.2
 #1  1      M    1    2    3    4
 #3  2      F    5    6    7    8
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2), Gender = c("M","F"), Q1 = c(1, 5), 
       Q2 = c(2, 6), Q3 = c(3, 7), Q4 = c(4, 8))

df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2), Gender = c("M", "M", "F", "F"),
   V1 = c(1, 3, 5, 7), V2 = c(2, 4, 6, 8))
```